# Update a column based on its current value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Is there any way to change field value based on its current value with one query?

Like I have `tbl.team` and if it's value `= 1`, change it to `2`. And vice versa, `tbl.team = 2` => `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a case expression to update the column conditionally:

```
update the_table
  set team = case 
                when team = 1 then 2
                else 1
             end
where team in (1,2);
```